# Why does the word "garage" have so many different pronunciations?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english

Whenever I'm teaching private students and we are faced with the word *garage*, I hesitate a little. Italians have borrowed the term *[garage](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/garage)*, which they pronounce  /**gaˈraʒ**/, to stand for the room/building where they keep their vehicles—also called a *box* in Italian.

In Italian the place where mechanics fix cars is not called a *garage*, but an *[officina](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/officina)*. And to confuse my students further, in BrEng a *garage* [*petrol station*] is also the place where you can buy petrol/gas (AmEng *gas station*.)

I hesitate before pronouncing this word, because I know it has several different pronunciations:

1. /**ˈɡærɑːʒ**/
2. /**ˈɡarɑː(d)ʒ**/ (I think this pronunciation is very similar to the first)
3. /**[ˈɡærɪdʒ](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/garage)**/

The first syllable is stressed whereas  in the following the stress is on the second syllable

4. /**gəˈräzh**/ or /**[ɡəˈrɑːʒ](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/garage)**/ and
5. /**ɡəˈrɑrʒ**/
   <sup>(non-standard U.S. Midwest pronunciation)</sup>

And I find myself pronouncing it in at least two ways, which befuddles the students (and makes me sound less credible!) I tell them that *garage* can be pronounced in more than one way but confess I don't know why. Personally, I blame it on the French :)

- Can someone explain why *garage* is pronounced in so many different ways?
- Which is the older pronunciation?

Comment: Numbers 4 and 5 are the same, in two different phonetic notations. But you left out the (non-standard and not to be encouraged) pronunciation from the U.S. Midwest with the extra /r/: /ɡəˈrɑrʒ/. (Although [Googling](https://www.google.com/#q=gararge) shows this pronunciation is much more widespread than just the Midwest.)

Comment: @PeterShor Ahh, I was wondering about no.4. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I can think of two common pronunciations in the US Midwest -- the more common "guh-raj", with the syllables slurred together and a slight accent on the 2nd syllable, and "GAY-raj", with a fairly strong accent on the 1st syllable.  I think in part the second one occurs simply because people like to "play" with the word, as it has a nice mouth feel and is used in a wide variety of contexts, many of which are amenable to playfulness.

Comment: Perhaps the optimal solution is the one I grew up with in Northern Illinois -- /graʒ/. It is irredeemably American, agreed; but it doesn't contrast with any other word in the language and gets the meaning across. In the USA _garage_ can encompass any combination of the meanings, and while we will recognize any other pronunciation as a British accent, we'll recognize the word.

Comment: When I grew up in North London, We said /ˈɡærɑːʒ/, and looked down on the lower-class people around us who said /ˈɡærɪdʒ/. But when I moved to Yorkshire, and gradually started talking Yorkshire (sometimes - depends who I'm talking to), I found that /ˈɡærɑːʒ/ seemed alien to it, and adopted /ˈɡærɪdʒ/. Now when I'm in the South and not talking Yorkshire, I don't know which to use: I think I say /ˈɡærɪdʒ/ more often.

Comment: When I lived in Calgary, Alberta, around 1970, I noticed that the most common pronunciation of _garage_ seemed to be _gradge_, rhyming with _badge_.

Comment: What?  No one has suggested *car hole*?

Comment: I vaguely remember an American book about life in the beginning of the 20th century. Automobiles were appearing and people were building "garages" to put them in. But nobody was sure how to pronounce this previously unknown word. The Google Ngram Viewer confirms that the word was practically unknown in English in 1900 but rose to half it s current popularity by 1920. Presumably it spread in print. People all over the world would suddenly see it in articles about the automobile and try to pronounce it. It is not surprising they pronounced it differently.

Comment: @DavidC that's interesting, I never thought of people not having *garages* before 1900s but it makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the Ngram tip! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=garage&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgarage%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I wonder why people stopped using garages in the 60s?

Comment: @HotLicks your comment is too cryptic for me, and goes waaay over my head. Never mind.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - There's a dramatic drop in the late 60s to early 70s.  Not clear why it would occur.  Curious.

Comment: @HotLicks Oh, you're referring to the Ngram, I posted that over a year ago. I hadn't a clue what you were on about.

Comment: [ɡəˈrɑ:dʒ] is another way supported by Kenyon & Knott.

Comment: 1 and 2 are the same, just in different notations; /æ/ and /a/ are not phonemically contrastive in any single dialect. You can lump them together as /ˈɡarɑː(d)ʒ/ or /ˈɡærɑː(d)ʒ/.

Comment: The main difference between UK and US English is the **tonic accent**.  In AmE, the stress (tonic accent) is on the age and in BrE it is on the ga. I think most Brits say petrol station for a gas station (AmE). And I only know one way to say it in AmE. But the sounds are the same. No point in going phonemic here at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, *garage* is a French loan and at first pronounced in the French way. After some time such words are pronounced in a way that is more conform to English pronunciation.

[OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/garage_1?q=garage) has three pronunciations for BrE (stress on the first syllable), and two for AmE (stress on the second syllable). Normally the most common pronunciation is given first. So in BrE the French pronunciation is still the most frequent.

Comment: I submit that no naive English speaker (unless natively bilingual in French) pronounces "garage" -- or any other word -- "the French way." Furthermore, the American stress on the second syllable sounds to my (American) ear far closer to the French than does the English stress on the first syllable.

Comment: But, but, but ... none of those pronunciations in the link is the way it OUGHT to be -- "GAY-rahj".

Comment: The link gives the pronunciations in BrE. You can switch to AmE.

Comment: The first three are BrE, the last two NAmE, none of them "GAY-rahj".

Answer (score 1):

Perfect example of “drift” in linguistics. Americans pronounce French derived words such as “courage” and “marriage” similar to the British way because they were already in usage at the time of separation. For Americans, “garage “ is derived directly from the French, not the English, and thus did not Anglicize it.

Answer (score 0):

Because /ʒ/ is not yet a full-fledged phoneme of English, so it's unstable.  Haj Ross noted that there is an alternation depending on stress between /ˈmjuːsɪˌlɑʒ/ and /ˈmjuːsɪlɪdʒ/, although dictionaries give only the latter.  I think that was in [A Reanalysis of English Word Stress](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/people/hayes/251English/Readings/Ross1972EnglishStress.pdf).

Comment: I tried reading that paper, but it's far too technical for me. Apparently, one must be well-versed with Chomsky's book *Sound Pattern of English* in order to comprehend the paper. No kidding :/

Comment: musilage. Found it! Page 253.

Comment: Actually, mucilage. And while I can't find a link, it occurred in a list of words which George Carlin presented as words which seem as if they should be offensive, even if they're not, just because of the way they sound.

Comment: My current Internet connection is slow as hell and that paper isn't loading—can you give some of the arguments for why /ʒ/ isn't to be considered a fully-fledged phoneme in English? Minimal chains like _loose/lose/luge_, _vision/pidgeon_, and _shush/zhuzh_ would seem to be good indicators that it is…

Comment: Ah, it finally loaded. He only seems to be saying that /ʒ/ and /dʒ/ are not distinguished _word-finally in polysyllabic words_, though: /dʒ/ only appears after a zero-stressed schwa, while /ʒ/ only appears after a stressed non-schwa when they come word-finally. He doesn't mention any other positions, but the minimal chains I noted above surely prove that they are distinct non-finally.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, ah! *shush/zhuzh* -- forgot about that one.  And we mustn't forget *shasha/Zsa Zsa*.  Good solid minimal pairs.

Comment: I agree that /ʒ/ and /d͡ʒ/ are separate phonemes, but could I suggest that with some words of relatively-recent French origin [such as garage] English-speakers feel that the soft G *ought* to be pronounced /ʒ/, while with words that have been with us at least since Chaucer's time [such as courage], the soft G is *always* pronounced /d͡ʒ/.  This introduces doubt, causing speakers to swing between those two sounds.